# c++ ctor body location produces erratic results

Tags: c++, c++11

I am developing a static library with a few classes and stumbled on something weird:

In my headers I have classes like this one:

```
class MyClass : public BaseClass {
    int k;
public:
    MyClass(int a,int b) : BaseClass(a) { k=b; }

    void func_1() { <whatever...> }

    int func_2(); // <- this body is in the .cpp
    ...
};
```

When I compile my test application everything compiles and work as expected.

Now I made a different set of headers (without any code, just method/ctor definitions) just to compile the test application, and  I get an unresolved external for each method or constructor from which I removed the body.

I thought that, once the library was compiled, the actual code was in the library, but it appears that if the code is in the header (aka inline), no actual code is put into the library. Is this normal?

Anyway, I moved the method/ctor bodies of the library from the headers to a cpp file (the few that had their body in the headers), recompiled the library and then also the test application with the same headers used to compile the library.
Now the test application compiles ok but produces erratic results (a lot of methods return random numbers).

I cut & paste again the code from the .cpp to the .h, recompile the library, and then the test application, and the test application works fine.

I cut & paste again the code from the .h to the .cpp (leaving just the declarations in the header), recompile the library, and then the test application, and the test application returns random results.

I cant understand whats going on: if I compile my library and test application with the headers in which the constructor body is defined, everythign works, if instead the constructor bodies are in the .cpp, I get wrong/random results.

Am I missing something? Shouldnt really be unimportant if the code for a method or constructor is defined in a header or a cpp file?

Comment: Are you properly initializing everything in the constructor that needs initializing?

Comment: yes they're really just very basic classes, most ctors just set an int

Comment: Could you show us one of the functions in your cpp file which produce random results but work fine when inlined?

Comment: the one in the exmaple. If MyClass ctor is in the .cpp, k will always be 0 no matter what. cut & paste into .h, and k = b. Except for the name, its one of the classes Im using

Comment: I'd like to see how it looks like when you _cut & paste_ it into the cpp file.

Comment: I see an explicit constructor where you have to set `a` and `b`, but what about the default constructor? Does `k` get initialized in there?

Comment: It will be the line shown above with a MyClass:: in front, while in the header there is only MyClass(int,int);

Comment: By the way, it is better to initialize `k` like this: `MyClass(int a, int b) : BaseClass(a), k(b) {}`

Comment: @Cyber no there is no default constructor..

Comment: What platform are you building for? Which compiler are you using?

Comment: Im using the Intel C++ on OpenSUSE 64bit

Comment: Did you do a complete rebuild in between? Maybe there is a problem regarding dependency checking resulting in the symbols not being updated in the library.

Comment: Im using CodeBlocks, I reparsed the project, Clean & Rebuild, and now automagically everything works.. meh.. sorry.. a simple rebuild was not enough

Answer (score 0):

Yes, methods defined inline in the header are usually not included in the generated object files. They may be included if they are called and the implementation decides that it is not willing or able to inline them, but you can never rely on this.

The same problem occurs when you want to call methods dynamically, i.e., using `dlsym` or similar facilities. You cannot get a method pointer to a method defined inline.